# Histogram of a categorical table in Matlab

Tags: matlab, count, unique, histogram

My table tNonNumeric consists of only categorical values. I try to find unique elements and how many times do they appear in my table. Not my actual data but following can be used instead:

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
FirstName = {'Amanda' ;'Brenda';'Carl'; 'Denis'; 'Ethan'};
Something = {'String1' ;'String2';'String2'; 'String1'; 'String5'};
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
FavoriteColor = {'blue' ;'red' ;'yellow'; 'orange' ;'colorblind' };
T = table(Age,FirstName,Weight,FavoriteColor,Something,'RowNames',LastName)
T.FavoriteColor= categorical(T.FavoriteColor);
T.Something= categorical(T.Something);
```

So how can I apply histogram to categorical values?

Answer (score 0):

Function histogram doesn't work with categorical data, but hist does:

```
hist(T.Something)
```

Comment: how about string values?